# Is asking if a movie soundtrack exists on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I was looking for a couple of meta posts to support the closure of a music trivia question when I stumbeled across [this answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/373/),which has a list of different soundtrack questions.  One of them I closed because it was off-topic, at least to my interpretation of trivia.  I also found these two other questions on the list that, at least to me, seem to be off-topic.  These questions ask whehter a movie has an official soundtrack and, if one is lacking, what songs were in the movie.

These questions don't go into any detail as to why the songs are important, and they don't really add to the appreciation of the movies.  So, should we consider these in the same vein as asking to identify songs or other music trivia?

- [Sennentuntschi (2010) official soundtrack](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1663/sennentuntschi-2010-official-soundtrack)
- [Does Dread (2009) have an official soundtrack?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85/does-dread-2009-have-an-official-soundtrack)

Answer (score 7):

I still stand by the points I made in that meta post.

If someone wants to know what songs are in X show, Google is to your left.

If someone wants to actually analyse a piece and ask its importance for a scene or even how a piece of music could relate to a movie in a well formatted way, then I would welcome that kind of question.

As it stands, just asking "What is this music" "where can I find the soundtrack" etc should be **Off-topic**.

Comment: No close votes (yet) though... Hmm...