# Why are music/score identification questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Just out of curiosity, why are music/score identification questions off-topic? Where should one go to answer these questions? The music SE site doesn't allow that kind of thing either.

I'm not for or against them, bit I'm just curious since they are related to movies and television.

Comment: Didn't look hard enough for the existing question. That's my fault. Vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should note that we're borderline happy as a community about identification questions at all.  We have some users (and moderators) who are pretty against them, and a few that like them a lot.  I'm on the fence, they don't add a lot but they do attract people to the site.

I think the simple answer is that we're not a Music site - so we don't allow 'identify this piece of music which just happens to be in a movie or TV show or music video' questions.

I don't think we'd consider an 'identify this movie from a score' to be off topic though.  That's an identification question with a movie as the objective.  It would be better if it were accompanied by other details, but personally I wouldn't close that.

Where should you go?  Well music.se is for "Musical Practice & Performance" so not there.  There is not currently a site for this on StackExchange.  You can try launching one using [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) - there are a number of Music related proposals needing support.

Answer (score 0):

What you should support the [Music Fans Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans).

Questions about music identification are going to be on topic there, but it is still on the commitment phase, so you can't ask questions as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in [this duplicate question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1296/49) it is still not 100% clear if they are off-topic or not. What can be seen though is, that they are definitely on-topic if they can provide further reasoning and inquiries on the usage of this piece of music in relation to the movie and further the apreciation of it, apart from just *"wanna listen to song"*, or no reason at all.

By the way, there is another [Music Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans?referrer=3OqVXGS9prFlGleSE5XxcQ2) underway, yet I for myself am certainly not going to start the dreaded ID discussion over there.