# Assuming song identification is still on-topic, is this community okay being referred as an alternative resource on Anime & Manga SE?

Tags: discussion, music-identification

[Anime.SE has just deprecated song identification](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/so-its-about-time-we-finally-deprecated-music-id-request-questions), thus inspired by [Movies.SE for providing the alternative resources](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/how-can-i-find-the-title-of-a-movie-from-just-a-description-or-image), we also have our own [**here**](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4189/what-identification-requests-are-acceptable-here-otherwise-where-else-can-i-po?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Currently, we are looking for alternative sites that still accept song identification (because [MusicFans.SE has also deprecated them](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/733/identification-questions-are-now-off-topic-heres-our-next-steps) before us). Searching from the network tags, it seems that Movies.SE still accepts song identification, as per [Do we have consensus on what makes a song-ID question on or off topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1632/do-we-have-consensus-on-what-makes-a-song-id-question-on-or-off-topic) and a quick peek at the search result for ["what song"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+what+song) questions.

Thus, before opening the possibility of a flood gate of low-quality song ID questions that have plagued Anime.SE:

1. Is this site open for being mentioned as an alternative site on a **comment**?
2. If yes, is this site also open to be **listed on the said meta post**?

(Of course, we'll try our best to provide recommended guidance before suggesting them to post on this site)

---

P.S. I previously asked for [similar permission on Meta Literature.SE](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1116/169) before.

Comment: A 2015 question isn't relevant. ID questions were outlawed several years ago (but after 2015), and for several years song questions had been closed and users were told to use the MusicFans SE for such questions once that SE came out of beta. For the record: that SE also doesn't accept ID questions anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### I would suggest not using M&TV as a resource

Personally I think a question asking why a particular piece of music was used in a scene is perfectly on topic here  - but I imagine that questions just asking for identification of music from a scene would be quickly downvoted and closed.

We do have an explicit ban on "identification" questions. By far the largest volume of ID questions related to the identification of movies, TV shows or episodes, the ban has covered less frequent types of question like the identification of Actors.

Music identification has not been a significant thing here. However I believe people would naturally extend our general ban on ID to include music.

Unless others think otherwise, I would not recommend using us as a resource.

Comment: Noted. Looks like I was misled when searching for "what song" questions on the main site because I only took a glance at the title but not the body, where it also mentioned something like "and why is this song used?" After reading [the FAQ](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4087/15983) thoroughly and noticing that [there's also a revision to remove MusicFans.SE as an alternative resource on here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/4130/revisions), I can see that song ID only is also off-topic. Thanks! :)